# I have Ricoh sp100su all in one , I don't know how to install the printer driver

Tags: drivers, printing

I have ricoh Sp100su printer. I don't know how to install the printer driver. From where I will get the driver software for both printing and scanning

Comment: please help,,,,,

Comment: hello......please help

Comment: so Open Printing; the source for support in linux; does not list your device but it does list similar devices; http://www.openprinting.org/printer/Ricoh/Ricoh-Aficio_SP_1000S and if you check through there to see what drivers are available; http://www.openprinting.org/printers/manufacturer/Ricoh